# Open Address Data for Restaurants

Tags: data-request, business, address

I am looking for any open data set that maintains restaurants (or places in general) with their address. If a place closes I am hoping this database will reflect that quickly.

Comment: Are you only interested in restaurants or in places in general? If it's the latter, you might want to change the title of your question accordingly. Also, are you only interested in places in the US or elsewhere too?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to connect to the restaurant/pub elements in OpenStreetMap data - and possibly report back mistakes and changes to OSM.

Comment: Point of Interest data from OSM is certainly one of your best starting points. But it's created by volunteers - don't expect to have all POI updated constantly or just after a restaurant closed. If you want to be up-to-date immediately you will most likely need to create yourself an app that derives information on change from various source like business registers, restaurant recommendations (e.g. when a new restaurant is at an existing address), local news, social networks etc - depending for which country / region / city you want to track that there might be specific sources

Comment: What's your geography? Restaurant inspection data can do this, but you there's not single national source?

Comment: As close to national as possible, global would be best but take what I can get.

Comment: "National"? Which nation?

Answer (score 12):

[OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) has quite an easily accessible database of restaurants (and other places), which you can easily query using their [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). An example query for [Overpass's Query Form](http://overpass-api.de/query_form.html) which gets all restaurants in greater London:

```
<query type="node">
  <has-kv k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
  <bbox-query s="51.28" n="51.686" w="-0.489" e="0.236"/>
</query>
<print/>
```

An easier way of creating a query is to use Overpass Turbo, which allows you to navigate a map to reflect your area of interest, again an [example of all restaurants in greater London](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/gP) (click on `Run` and move to the `Data` tab on the upper right to see the 'raw' data).

Another source is [OpenCorporates](http://opencorporates.com/), which often holds official registrations of companies and whether they are active or not. Many restaurant registrations don't have their address listed, but you might want to use their data to find out whether restaurants are still active or not ([see their video](https://vimeo.com/17924204) on how to use Google/OpenRefine to reconcile names from a certain dataset (in this case OpenStreetMaps) with the OpenCorporates dataset).

Comment: Wah! Just what I need (-ish). Do you know how to query that with Leaflet? Or even just plain JS (that looks like HTML, but it doesn't, if you know what I mean, so I imagine you are using a framework, but don't know which one)

Answer (score 7):

The SimpleGeo point of interest dump of 21m places is the best open data set I know of, though it's getting pretty long in the tooth these days and so won't have the up-to-date-ness you're looking for:

http://archive.org/details/2011-08-SimpleGeo-CC0-Public-Spaces

Answer (score 5):

[Wikivoyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org) has open data about restaurants and bars, worldwide, pretty up-to-date.

The data is licensed under [Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

The format is like this:

```
{{eat
| name=Atelier de Joel Robuchon | url=http://www.robuchon.jp/latelier | email=
| address=Roppongi Hills Hillside 2F, 6-10-1 Roppongi
| lat=35.660197 | long=139.728804 | directions=
| phone=+81 3 5772-7500 | tollfree= | fax=
| hours=11:00–22:00 daily | price=
| content=The first overseas venture of the eponymous [[Paris]]-based Michelin-starred chef.  Each dish is a work of art almost as breathtaking as the price tag, as courses cost ¥2900–¥12,800 &mdash; still a steal by Tokyo gourmet standards.  No reservations are accepted, so prepare to queue.
}}
```

You are probably interested in the `name` and `address` field. Concatenate the the name of the article (country and city) to the `address`, and tha makes the full address.

Notes:

- It does not contain ALL restaurants, but rather a selection of about 10 restaurants for each small city (or each part of a big city).
- As far as I know, DBpedia does not parse Wikivoyage yet. This means you will have to [download the XML dump](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwikivoyage/) (enwikivoyage-xxx-pages-articles.xml.bz2) and write a small script to extract the name-address couples.

Comment: I like it because I think it has a lot of future potential, but how do you access the data? Any API or dump?

Comment: @djc391: Thanks for the feedback! I added the information about how to access the data.

Answer (score 1):

Local health departments are often the agencies that keep license and inspection information. Yelp and a few cities have been working to develop a national standard for inspection data (LIVES), but not too many places have adopted this yet.

Answer (score 1):

open tables sounds like the ticket:
http://www.opentable.com/state.aspx

edit: although i just clicked through state and onto a city...doesn't look like a straightforward list. @ least not offhand.

Answer (score 0):

[Yelp](http://www.yelp.com/) has a search and business API and you can find more details on their [developers page](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, since this is the Open Data SE, we are looking for open datasets. The data from Yelp is copyrighted, so it's not really helpful here.

Comment: That's very helpful. Is it ok to delete a bad answer?

Comment: If you think you can improve your answer, you can edit it. Of course it's also fine to delete your answer. These [tips on how to answer](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) might also be helpful :)

Comment: Yelp is not open data. Yelp is owned by google and can't be used but thank you.

Comment: On some other stack exchange sites, I've edited the answer to strike it out -- to mark that my answer was flawed, if there was a good chance that someone else might give the same response.