# Yelp datasets: Business name, phone number, and address

Tags: data-request, business

I am looking for business data via a query search by geography. I would like to have:

- Business Name
- Phone Number
- Address, either from Yelp or the Yellow Pages

As an example: Coffee Shops in California listed on Yelp.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/691/3115